# fetching from text file or database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have to display data consisting of **approx. 1000 character**.

Right now, I am using a text file and fetching it from there line by line till end of file and displaying it through **AJAX**.

But its quite slow.

**I wanted to know if i store that data in database as `text` would it make difference ?**

Comment: You should test and find out.

Comment: Storing info as `text` in databases can be a pretty ineffecient type if you're after speed... Chances are a text file and a database aren't going to be much different when you're only talking about 1000 characters... If you want to find out, get it going both ways, put it in a loop 500 times or so and measure the time.

Comment: Storing it in a database and using an INDEX key would certainly be beneficial and would speed up queries considerably in doing so.

Comment: Why store it as `text`? Is there no maximum string length you can foresee/restrict the stored value to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It does depend on how many lines there are tho. If there aren't many lines, it won't make much of a difference.

I would recommend (for something small) a txt file on the server and directly getting it directly with AJAX, without the addition step of php and sql.

Comment: I used AJAX directly with file. Its working great now. But i don't want user to see the path of text file is it possible using this way ?

Comment: What's wrong with them seeing the path? Few will bother to look in the web inspector to find it anyway. There isn't going to be a way to hide the path, since it will have to be downloaded so js can execute it. If you are serious about it being secret, you will have to use php.

Comment: But still.. Safety is better than cure.. if there is any kindly help me with that..:)

Comment: What is the safety issue?

Comment: Actually my client don't want the source of the data file to be discovered as it makes the system vulnerable. So..

Comment: ...php. Use phil-lavin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to read line by line. You can read the full string with:

```
file_get_contents('/path/to/file')
```

I cannot foresee storing the text in a single database row/field will improve efficiency at all.

Answer (score 1):

actually storing text in database can slowdown performance, looks like your problem is in line-by-line reading, read about [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or [file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) or the best way [readfile](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)